# Whether "I" takes singular or plural verb?

Tags: tense, personal-pronouns

I'm confused with this especially in english grammar exams.
What should I use while answering concepts like Tenses and Subject Verb Agreement?  Will "I" takes singular or plural verb?

Comment: How many 'I's are you?

Comment: Is it confusing to you because you don't know whether you should say *I do* or *I does*, or because you don't know which verb form is called singular and which is called plural?

Comment: @rogermue Put that in an answer and cite it; it's pretty helpful and will get more attention that way.

Comment: hmm . . . maybe something like: *"If **I were** you, I wouldn't kick that sleeping bear"*, er,  . . . :)

Answer (score 1):

The word *I* is singular, and it takes a singular verb. Here are some simple examples.

Present time:

> I **am walking** to the store right now.

Past time:

> I **walked** to the store yesterday.

Future time:

> I **am walking** to the store 5 minutes from now.

(Yes, it is true that *I am walking to the store* can refer to the present moment or to the future. The adverb of time clarifies when, as does context.)

Another common way to the refer to future time:

> I **will walk** to the store tomorrow.

Here the verb *walk* is in the bare infinitive, because it follows the helping verb *will*.

When you add another person, the verb becomes plural. In this case, the singular *am* is replaced by the plural *are*:

> Sara and I **are walking** to the store.

(This can be talking about the present moment or about the future, as above. Without an adverb of time, it usually refers to the present moment. Remember, these are simple examples only.)

For simple past the plural verb has the same form as the singular verb:

> Sara and I **walked** to the store yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have no knowledge of basic grammar terms. I would recommend try to find two basic grammars for beginners in public libraries and see which one suits you best. Without sure knowledge of the basic grammar terms you will always have difficulty understanding explanations.

Here you can see a table of the verb forms of present tense. Normal verbs are very simple, there is only one ending -s, which is used when the subject is a noun in singular which can be replaced by he/she/it.

There are some verbs which have particularites, but they are only a handful.

This is the table of present tense of the normal verb to eat:

first person singular ---I eat

second person singular-- you eat

third person singular -- he/she/it eats

first person plural ---- we eat

second person plural --- you eat

third person plural ---- they eat

http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/learn-english/grammar/simple-present/

Comment: It may be a good idea to put the tables directly in your answer and cite them so that future users can see them if the link is changed.

Comment: Good advice, @Blubberguy22